# Permutation of people and teams

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

Suppose 20 people attend an event where there is 4 different activities to do. Suppose we want to split the group in subgroups, each subgroup attending one session of an activity, then moving on the other activities...

Is it possible to arrange things so that at the end of the day everybody has attended every activity exactly once and so that everybody has meet all 19 other people exactly once (by participating to an activity with them) ?

i.e. if A and B attend the first activity together, they wont meet again later that day.

For what size of crowd is this possible (if my random choice of considering 20 people doesnt give a solution) ?

Comment: I'm trying to picture the situation as best as I can with my limited knowledge of english... Maybe my lack of proficiency explains the downvotes...

Comment: I am not one of the downvoters but can you explain your statement that there are 20 people and "for what size of crowd is this possible"? Why are you saying that there are 20 people if your question is how many people there are?

Comment: I said "20 people" to make it simpler. Maybe its not possible to get a solution for 20 people. But maybe there exists a solution for another number... I pick 20 randomly and it would be sad if my choice was unfortunate because I feel that this is an interesting question.

Comment: How do we solve this kind of question ? If 20 doesnt work, then let's pick another number and lets discuss how to tackle this kind of question.

Comment: So in your question 20 is not fixed, but four activities are fixed, or that too can vary?

Comment: That too can vary.

Comment: Do you know of balanced incomplete block designs because I think that is what you are wanting?

Comment: I dont but I'll google it.

Comment: This is somewhat close to the [Social Golfer Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html). See also, [Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem). I think @Shahab pretty much nailed it, with the suggestion. [Combinatorial designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design) seem to be a pretty vast area, and there's even a tag ([tag:combinatorial-designs]) for it here.

Comment: Very many thanks guys, at least now I got a better idea in what direction to look ! This Social Golfer Problem is exactly what I was trying to formulate here.